# Recursive typedef definition using std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I want to define a `std::variant` that can store a vector of pairs, with strings and Values.

I want to create a structure like below:

```
typedef std::variant<bool, int, float, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Value>>> Value;
```

How can I do it in C++17?

Comment: Put the variant in a struct, and pass the struct to `pair` template parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As HolyBlackCat notes in the comments, you need `Value` to be a type (but it can be incomplete) to use it in the pair.

```
struct Value
{
    std::variant<bool, int, float, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Value>>> data;
};
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/826ec1d987fe75e7)

Comment: In my code base the Value is used as std::variant in other places. Is there a way that I can hold the Value type as variant? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Extended example: https://godbolt.org/z/d95eq1YqW

Comment: Here is version where `Value` is still a `std::variant`: https://godbolt.org/z/abTKasbo1 this should better fit into your existing code base.